# change of variable in two dimension

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Result: Let $T\in GL(d, \mathbb R).$ If $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function on $\mathbb R^d, $ so is $f\circ T.$ If $f\geq 0$ or $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$, then 
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d} f(x) dx = |\text{det} \  T| \int_{\mathbb R^d} f\circ T (x) dx.$$

e.g., Let $T:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2, T(x,y)=f(x+y, x-y).$ Then by above result
we have
$$\int_{\mathbb R^2} f(x,y) dx dy = 2 \int_{\mathbb R^2} f(x+y, x-y) dx dy.$$

Put $h(x,y)= f(x+y, x-y).$

**Question**:I'm trying to prove the above formula without using any result:
$I=\int_{\mathbb R^2} h(x,y) dx dy= \int_{\mathbb R^2} f(x+y, x-y) dx dy. $  If take substitution $u=x+y, v=x-y,$ then  $I=\int_{\mathbb R^2} f(u,v) dx dy$
I think, I should transform my $dx, dy$ and in terms of $du, dv$. I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways to read your question.   You might be asking "How can I prove the change-of-variables formula for double integrals?"   Or you might be asking "Is there a more convenient way to calculate these things than writing down a matrix and calculating the determinant?"    I'll assume what you want is the second thing.

The language of [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) provides a convenient means of expressing these kinds of calculations.   Instead of $dxdy$, we write $dx \wedge dy$.   The wedge is a product, but it is no longer commutative.   Instead it obeys the rule $dx \wedge dy = -dy \wedge dx$.    Instead of representing a scalar quantity, $dx\wedge dy$ is a thing called a 2-form, which you can think of as a quantity that can be integrated over an oriented 2 dimensional domain.

We can use the rules of $d$ and $\wedge$ to calculate $du \wedge dv$:

$$
du \wedge dv = d(x+y)\wedge d(x-y) = (dx + dy)\wedge(dx - dy) 
\\
=(dx\wedge dx) - (dx\wedge dy) + (dy\wedge dx) - (dy \wedge dy)
\\
= 0 - (dx\wedge dy) - (dx\wedge dy) - 0
\\
= -2 dx \wedge dy 
$$